# About quadratic form and its discriminant

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

There are 3 parts of the problem.

1. Let d be a perfect square, possibly 0. Show that there is a quadratic form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0$ of discriminant d for which a=0.
2. Let a,b,c be integers with $a\ne0$. Show that if one root of the eqatuion $au^2+bu+c=0$ is rational then the other one is, and that $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square, possibly 0.
3. Show also that if $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square, possibly 0, then the roots of the equation $au^2+bu+c=0$ is rational.

For question 1., I wrote $d=k^2$ for some integer k. Then, I got to $b^2-k^2=4ac$ and got stuck.

For question 2 and 3, all the claims of the problem sounds perfectly right (which should be always right...) and I couldn't start from both of those ones.

Thank you.

Comment: 3 is false, e.g., let $b=\pi$, $a=\sqrt2$, $c=\pi^2/(4\sqrt2)$. But if $a,b,c$ are integers, then it follows immediately from the quadratic formula. The quadratic formula is also key to the 2nd question. For the 1st question, you appear to have forgotten that $a=0$.